# CORS Preflight Request: Must all Headers in `Access-Control-Request-Headers` be permitted for 2XX response?

Tags: spring, cors

I was writing an integration test leveraging v5.3.20 of Spring Framework's [`DefaultCorsProcessor`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.3.20/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/cors/DefaultCorsProcessor.java) implementation, and I found that as long as any single HTTP Request header in [`Access-Control-Request-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Request-Headers) is allowed, it will consider the entire CORS preflight request valid ([Source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.3.20/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/cors/DefaultCorsProcessor.java#L134-L139)). The [`Access-Control-Allowed-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers) will include the intersection of those found in the [`Access-Control-Request-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Request-Headers) and those allowed via [`CorsConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.3.20/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/cors/CorsConfiguration.java) ([Source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.3.20/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/cors/DefaultCorsProcessor.java#L147-L149)).

Their GitHub `CONTRIBUTING.md` says to ask questions on StackOverflow ([Source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.3.20/CONTRIBUTING.md#discuss)), so here we are:

**Should *all* HTTP Request headers in the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` CORS Preflight Request Header be allowed for a preflight to get a successful response, or is it fine if *any* of the listed HTTP Request headers are allowed?**

I can't tell if this is a bug in Spring Framework or an implementation detail left up to CORS implementers. [The WHATWG docs](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-cors-protocol), which Mozilla and W3C point to as the authoritative source on the topic, do not provide an example or sufficient clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in the preflight response are a strict subset of the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` in the preflight request, the client will *not* make the subsequent request. This server behaviour is fine, it is up to the client to draw the correct conclusion.

See step 7 of the [CORS-preflight fetch specification](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-preflight-fetch).

Comment: Great, that's the current behavior. Can you provide a link to authoritative documentation on the topic?

Comment: See my augmented answer.

Comment: Ah, nice! It's documented much better on the client side. I accepted this answer.